# How to avoid chaos with AppScripts Triggers running in multiple copied spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Thanks in advance for any help.

**I'll outline my requirement first:**

- I need ~200 different teams to each own their own google spreadsheet, and I need a single data source that pulls from these different spreadsheets.

**My plan to achieve this:**

- I will share a link to **copy** my central spreadsheet, with AppScripts written. When they each make their own copy, there is a button that sets up a Timed Trigger, such that each week their data will be copied into a central location. I've got all of this working fine, with as much error handling as I can think of.

**My Problem**

- Let's consider a scenario where Person A (In Team 1) makes a copy of the spreadsheet, but forgets where they saved it, so they make a new copy. They now have two spreadsheets which are *both* trying to copy data into my central location. This same thing could also happen if multiple people from Team 1 both make their own copies.
- I'm worried we could end up with hundreds of spreadsheets, all stored in different locations, all copying to the same spreadsheet once per week, which could become impossible to track down.

1. What solutions do you have?
   *2) As a side question, when a spreadsheet gets deleted (moved to Bin), does the timed trigger stop running?*

Current approach will be to check weekly if I'm getting several inputs from the same team. In which case I'll need to reach out to that team and ask them to delete any old spreadsheets. There are obvious concerns with this.

Alternatively I could not allow anyone to make their own copies - in stead I could make 200 copies myself of the original spreadsheet. Not something I want to do for my own sanity.